# An unexpected error was encountered while executing a WSL command

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Common causes include access rights issues, which occur after waking the computer or not being connected to your domain/active directory.
Please try shutting WSL down (wsl --shutdown) and/or rebooting your computer. If not sufficient, WSL may need to be reinstalled fully. As a last resort, try to uninstall/reinstall Docker Desktop. If the issue persists please collect diagnostics and submit an issue (Troubleshoot Docker Desktop | Docker Docs).
why when I install docker on windows 11 it keeps getting an error like this, what to do?[image]

I've tried uninstalling docker and wsl again but it's still like that. Please give instructions so it can be installed. I've been trying it for 5 days

Comment: I've found the solution